# Homological Methods in commutative Algebra Reference | lecture notes/ video lectures

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, local-rings, dimension-theory-algebra, regular-rings

I am studying Homological Methods in Commutative Algebra,TIFR Bombay pamphlet ([this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi22-ya9ND5AhV0nFYBHX29DJ4QFnoECB4QAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.tifr.res.in%2F%7Epubl%2Fpamphlets%2Fhomological.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3feEGnIhMeKVtO8SCGF_D2)). Can anyone suggest any good reference/ notes/ video lectures for this? I am feeling lost. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is entirely normal to get lost there if you're a beginner. It would be preferable if you thoroughly researched those topics in other materials/books. N.S. Gopalakrishnan's "Commutative Algebra" and Matsumura's "Commutative Ring Theory" are two of the most popular books.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! I completed this few months back and had followed these books mainly as reference.

Answer (score 0):

Here's link to a textbook on local cohomology: [link](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/local-cohomology/58A833CCD2D0F834644781AFB1351657).